# r: how to mutate a new category based inputs from group_by() with multiple and different information?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

Let's say I have:

```
> df
  RECNUM diag.letter diag.number C_DIAG
1      A           S           6  DS060
2      A           T          15  DT151
3      A           S           6 DS061A
4      B           S           6  DS064
5      C           S           6  DS061
6      C           S           6  DS066
7      D           S           2  DS020
8      D           S           2  DS021
```

I am trying to define different types of traumas based on these information. I want to create `df$trauma` which have three levels: "Iso.TBI", "Multi.TBI" and "Multitrauma".

I seek a solution in `dplyr`

The criteria are:

(1) `group_by(RECNUM)` or similar.

(2) If `df$RECNUM` has more than one row (more than one unique RECNUM), and all these rows contain `diag.letter == "S"` in combination with `diag.number == 6` OR more than one of these characters:`C_DIAG %in% c("DS020", "DS021", "DS029", "DS071")`, then **Multi.TBI**

(3) `else if` `diag.letter` contains "T" - regardless of how many rows, then **Multi.traume**,

(4) Else **Iso.TBI**

Here is the **expected output**

```
> df
  RECNUM diag.letter diag.number C_DIAG      trauma
1      A           S           6  DS060 Multitrauma
2      A           T          15  DT151 Multitrauma
3      A           S           6 DS061A Multitrauma
4      B           S           6  DS064     Iso.TBI
5      C           S           6  DS061   Multi.TBI
6      C           S           6  DS066   Multi.TBI
7      D           S           2  DS020   Multi.TBI
8      D           S           2  DS021   Multi.TBI
```

Data

```
 df <- data.frame(
   RECNUM = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "C", "C", "D", "D"),
   diag.letter = c("S", "T", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S"),
   diag.number = c(6, 15, 6, 6, 6, 6, 2, 2),
   C_DIAG = c("DS060", "DT151", "DS061A", "DS064", "DS061", "DS066", "DS020", "DS021")
 )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good candidate for `dplyr::case_when` within `dplyr::mutate()` - note `case_when` evaluates one-after-another, so order is important. This first looks for any "T" in `C_DIAG` using `grepl`, since that will override any of the other logic. Then, among those with no "T" in any of the `C_DIAG`, it performs the remaining logic you described in (2) and (4) (note: `n()` provides the number of rows by `RECNUM`):

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(trauma = case_when(
    any(grepl("T", diag.letter)) ~ "Multitrauma",
    n() > 1 & all(diag.letter == "S") & diag.number == 6 ~ "Multi.TBI",
    C_DIAG %in% c("DS020", "DS021", "DS029", "DS071") ~ "Multi.TBI",
    TRUE ~ "Iso.TBI"
  ),
    .by = RECNUM
)
```

Output:

```
  RECNUM diag.letter diag.number C_DIAG      trauma
1      A           S           6  DS060 Multitrauma
2      A           T          15  DT151 Multitrauma
3      A           S           6 DS061A Multitrauma
4      B           S           6  DS064     Iso.TBI
5      C           S           6  DS061   Multi.TBI
6      C           S           6  DS066   Multi.TBI
7      D           S           2  DS020   Multi.TBI
8      D           S           2  DS021   Multi.TBI
```

Comment: @GregorThomas ha, agreed!

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if all the nesting is right, but this matches your result:

```
c_diag_vals = c("DS020", "DS021", "DS029", "DS071")

df |>
  mutate(trauma = case_when(
    ## more than one row AND
    n() > 1 & (
      (  ## all rows have diag.letter "S" and diag.number 6
        all(diag.letter == "S") & all(diag.number == 6)  
      ) |
        ## or there is more than one unique value from c_diag_vals vector
      length(setdiff(c_diag_vals, C_DIAG)) < (length(c_diag_vals) - 1)
    ) ~ "Multi.TBI",
    ## any diag.letter is "T"
    any(diag.letter == "T") ~ "Multi.trauma",
    ## else
    .default = "Iso.TBI"
  ), .by = RECNUM)

#   RECNUM diag.letter diag.number C_DIAG       trauma
# 1      A           S           6  DS060 Multi.trauma
# 2      A           T          15  DT151 Multi.trauma
# 3      A           S           6 DS061A Multi.trauma
# 4      B           S           6  DS064      Iso.TBI
# 5      C           S           6  DS061    Multi.TBI
# 6      C           S           6  DS066    Multi.TBI
# 7      D           S           2  DS020    Multi.TBI
# 8      D           S           2  DS021    Multi.TBI
```